# Is there any evidence for dual-wielding in the 12th Century?

Tags: weapons, 12th-century

To settle an office debate - I was wondering if there was any evidence for any soldier or knight in the 12th Century using two weapons at once - for instance, if a shield was dropped or wasn't available.

Is there anything that could confirm this? A lot of searching hasn't turned anything up yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, depends on *where* in the 12th century... some Indian and East Asian fencing weapons were meant to be deployed as a pair. I am assuming you mean medeval Europe.

The earliest tome on swordsmanship is an untitled work known simply as [I.33](http://www.thearma.org/Manuals/i33/i33.htm), and dates to 1300. It concerns itself only with buckler and longsword, which were in fashion at the time. Later into the 14th century, the aphorisms of [Johannes Liechtenauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Liechtenauer) were recorded by contemporaries... but they made no mention of dual-weapon technique.

Any fighting technique used by feudal knights or soldiery earlier than this is not documented by history - accounts of battle generally notes who killed who, not blow-by-blow reconstructions of the melee. Likewise, [art depicting battle](http://rubens.anu.edu.au/htdocs/bytype/textiles/bayeux/) usually modelled the knights in their finest regalia, not in the disarray of actual combat.

Considering a shield is a weapon in its own right, and one the medeval combatant had likely trained with, they'd go for an abandoned or improvised shield before a spare sword if they found their shield hand empty.